# External fund transfer Internet banking

Tags: money-transfer, online-banking

Recently I got the internet banking service and I want to make an external fund transfer to a bank in USA am in Jordan. and I have to fill the following fields to complete the transaction [image]

Beneficiary bank: The bank name

Beneficiary name: it is clear the name of the person I am going to send money to

Account number: it is clear also also the city and country.

My question is about the 1) Beneficiary branch, and 2)the three address lines below are they for the bank? what about the routing number?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at transfer services like Transferwise, Currencywise? It might be easier and cheaper.

Comment: I am going to travel to USA and I do not have a bank account there yet. I have a good amount of money in my bank here ( exceed 10k $) and I do not want to carry it with me. So I ordered the internet banking so I can transfer my money to my future bank account while I am in USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be best answered by your Bank.

If the Bank and Branch are free text; there is no way your Bank will know the details. In this case put the routing number in the IBAN/Account Number along with space or hyphen and put the Account Number.

If the Bank / Branch are look up; your Bank can find the routing number [as these would be stored].